# Warum ist der Titel des Stückes von Mozart "Eine Kleine Nachtmusik" und nicht "Ein Bisschen Musik" oder "Etwas Musik"?

Tags: word-choice

Das weibliche Wort Musik gehört doch zu den unabzählbaren.

Comment: Die *Unzählbarkeit* von Musik ist erst in der Neuzeit entstanden. In früheren Zeiten war damit auch ein einzelnes *Musikstück* oder ein einzelner Vortrag gemeint. Siehe http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM08549#XGM08549

Comment: @tofro "eine Musik" hört man immer noch gelegentlich, besonders im Theater/Fernsehen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Wort Musik hat mehrere Bedeutungen:

1. Musik ist eine Kunstgattung, deren Werke aus organisierten Schallereignissen bestehen. (Quelle: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musik))
   In diesem Sinn ist Musik tatsächlich etwas unabzählbares. Es gibt nicht noch eine zweite Kunstgattung, deren Werke aus organisierten Schallereignissen bestehen, sondern nur diese eine Kunstgattung, deren Namen eben »die Musik« ist.
2. Ein Musikstück.
   In diesem Sinn gibt es tatsächlich viele verschiedene Musiken, und die sind durchaus abzählbar. So wurden z.B. in der Frühzeit des Radios Musikstücke extra fürs Radio komponiert, und diese Musiken nannte man »[Radiomusiken](http://www.rundfunkschaetze.de/edition-radiomusiken/)«

Mozarts kleine Nachtmusik ist so eine Musik im Sinne der Definition 2. Es ist eine Musik für die Nacht, und es ist kein großes Werk, sondern ein kleines, und daher ist es eben *eine kleine Nachtmusik*

Answer (score 0):

Es handelt sich ganz einfach um ein **Adjektiv**, das ein Nomen näher beschreibt:

> Eine grüne Gurke
>
> Eine alte Frau
>
> Eine kleine Nachtmusik

Alle diese Ausdrücke stehen hier im Nominativ, da sie ja nicht innerhalb eines Satzes als Objekt verwendet werden. Ein Adjektiv übernimmt immer den Fall, die Zahl und das Geschlecht des Nomens, zu dem es gehört.

---

Das **bisschen** im Ausdruck

> Ein bisschen Musik

ist hingegen ein Pronomen mit der Bedeutung **kleines etwas**.

Comment: Es ist sinvoll dann, zu sagen "ein Wasser" oder "ein Glück" wenn die Menge für etwas unzählbar gemeint ist?

Comment: Das sind zwei weitere Fragen, die mit dieser Frage nichts zu tun haben.

Comment: Ich habe es jetzt repariert

Comment: Die Antwort geht an der Frage vorbei, die zugegebenermaßen schlecht zu entschlüsseln war, aber dann muss man halt nachfragen.

Comment: Nein, tut sie nicht. Für Adjektive wie *klein* spielt Abzählbarkeit überhaupt keine Rolle.

Comment: Ich glaube, es geht dem Fragesteller darum, dass er das Konzept „eine Musik“ nicht versteht.

Comment: @Philipp ...und das glaube ich auch. Daher mein Kommentar oben.